# ANT+ C# ANT managed library Cannot get list of devices, only 1

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand  ANT+ and the C# library they have produced. I have spent a few weeks understanding it and binary and have been looking at a way of implementing it using a Console App. Initially to get a list of devices.....However, when using

```
   channelScan.channelResponse += new dChannelResponseHandler(ScanResponse);
```

I only ever get 1 data page, in which I can I identify the Correct DeviceID, DeviceType and TransType.... but only ever 1..

Im using

```
 device0.setNetworkKey(0, USER_NETWORK_KEY);
 device0.setLibConfig(ANT_ReferenceLibrary.LibConfigFlags.MESG_OUT_INC_DEVICE_ID_0x80 | ANT_ReferenceLibrary.LibConfigFlags.RADIO_CONFIG_ALWAYS_0x01 | ANT_ReferenceLibrary.LibConfigFlags.MESG_OUT_INC_RSSI_0x40 );
              
  device0.enableRxExtendedMessages(true);
```

and also setting ChannelID to 0, so I can scan the whole range.... but still only one line.

Am I missing some concept? Are the devices Hz too in sync, so I get the same page, but not the others. I use ANTWare II to test my settings, and they are fine, I can see all devices, so it must be my code.

I tried writing my own code, and I can get deviceIDs, from 1, not all. I also have tried  changing the ChannelID to 1,2,3,4 and obviously doesnt work.

Im just stuck, maybe I missed an idea somewhere.